# RegEx a-zA-Z or a-zA-Z followed by - and a-zA-Z

Tags: regex

I need the following regex that allows

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

or

```
[a-zA-Z]+[ \\-]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+
```

so I want to allow unlimited minus and spaces between a-zA-Z characters

Example:

```
sdfsdfdsf-sfsdfs
sdfdsf-sdfsd-sdfdsf-sdfsdf-sdf-sdf-sdfsd-f
sdfdsf sdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdf-sdfsdf
```

How cn I do that?

Comment: You should tag your question with the relevant language you're using because different regex engines have different syntax/capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked many times, but for future users I will include a solution:

```
[a-zA-Z]+([ -][a-zA-Z]+)*
```

(Start with `a-zA-Z`, then optionally include `[ -][a-zA-Z]` 0 times or more `*`)

Though depending on exact requirements you could clean it up by using `\w`

```
\w+([ -]\w+)*
```

If this is a single string you are matching, rather than finding it in a larger string, you would want a start and end anchor:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+([ -][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

Comment: be careful with using \w. it matches [0-9a-zA-Z_] instead of [a-zA-Z]

Answer (score 2):

You just want to repeat `-XXX` blocks?

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)*
```

(Note that `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group; the syntax for this varies by Regex engine).

Comment: You forgot to anchor the expression.

Comment: You don't need to escape the minus in the character class (when it's first or last)

Comment: @Sniffer: OP didn't imply he needed anchoring. I don't add it unless necessary. Sometimes, Regex is used for searching.

Comment: @Bohemian: Force of habit and symmetry with OP's regex. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as brief as I think it can be:

```
(?i)[a-z]+([ -]+[a-z]+)*
```

You don't need to escape the minus in the character class when it's first or last.

By using the "ignore case" switch, the regex shortens a bit too.